# Possible OBD-II/OBD2 connections for development phases

Tags: embedded, bluetooth, automotive, obd, block-diagram

Is there any paper/document that summarizes all connection scenarios or cases when you are developing an [OBD-II/OBD2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics) project for automative/car electronics?
For instance,

- Scenario 1 : Real car -> cabled <- Converter/Dongle -> bluetooth <- OBD-II scanner mobile app
- Scenario 2 : Real car -> cabled <- Converter/Dongle -> wireless  <- OBD-II scanner mobile app
- Scenario 3 : Real car -> cabled <- Converter/Dongle -> cabled    <- OBD-II scanner mobile app
- Scenario 4 : Hardware ECU Emulator -> cabled <- Converter/Dongle -> cabled    <- OBD-II scanner mobile app
- ...
- Scenario .. : Virtual ECU Emulator ->  inner <- OBD-II scanner mobile app
- ...

The above ones are the scenarios that I can just imagine right now. However, I would like to see a paper that summarizes all possible options with possibly example brands, devices, applications, software, etc?
Thanks

Comment: It would be odd to find an exhaustive list, either way I think this is off-topic here. There are a thousands of connection/app scenarios, and it really doesn't make a lot of sense to make a list of them because its ever-evolving.

Comment: My list is only an example starting step. The point is here is there any paper or article that summarize the categorization in this manner. I am not looking for exact list. For instance, I named the last one in my list as virtual emulator, is this exactly correct, preferred and exist term and component? There are tons of questuons in addition to the preperation of single long list.

Comment: You can get the appropriate ISO and SAE documents, they will be correct and have that information or enough to do what you want.